# Is it helpful, how is it possible, to deal with anger by 'accepting' it with equanimity?

Tags: theravada, anger

I'm new to Buddhism and I had just started to put some of the teachings into practice. But I'm having great difficulty dealing with my anger. I have always been rather intense in my emotions. I get angered quite easily. I've done some reading and I'm still stuck. I need some help on the way forward.

From the readings I've done, I was told to practice forbearance, which is something I'm actually quite used to doing. But the things is, instead of expressing it, the anger is seething inside of me, and I would be passive aggressive, which is also wrong. From doing this, I would get a headache and waste a great portion of the day.

Then, I've read that I should practice metta towards my anger, accepting it with equanimity. So, this morning when I was angry, I tried but failed. I would tell myself that being angry is normal, but the anger still remained in me for a long time.

So, actually, I'm rather confused with this acceptance of anger. How does it help in any way?

Thanks all.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Buddhism SE. We also have a [*Help Center*](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) with useful resources for new comers. Enjoy your time here.

Comment: There are several other questions (topics) on this site which are tagged [tag:anger], and which you might find helpful to read. So that this is slightly different and not a duplicate of other topics, I edited this question's title to make it more specific.

Comment: related questions: [Dispelling anger](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/dispelling-anger), [Anger management - How to manage bad temper?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/anger-management-how-to-manage-bad-temper)

Answer (score 10):

In Buddhism, there are many methods to deal with anger.

The method of **accepting anger** is a method of 'non-conflict'. By fully acknowledging & accepting anger in an open way, you can develop some objectivity towards & independence from the anger (in that it will not control your behaviour) and, importantly, give anger the space to subside.

The method I personally prefer & the method most used by the Buddha before his enlightenment was to **wisely reflect** (think about) the harm & dangers of anger; in how anger can harm yourself & harm others.

If you are often habitually & uncontrollably angry:

(1) You feel bad about yourself (afterwards).

(2) You become tense & can harm the health of your body & mind.

(3) People may dislike, fear or avoid you.

(4) Important relationships can be harmed, broken & lost.

(5) You can lose your job (employment) & develop a bad reputation.

The scriptures state:

> *As I abided...a thought of ill will (anger) arose in me. I understood thus: ‘This thought of anger has arisen in me. This leads to my own
> affliction (harm), to others’ affliction and to the affliction of
> both; it obstructs wisdom, causes difficulties (vexation) and leads
> away from peace.‘ When I considered thus…it subsided in me. Whenever a
> thought of anger arose in me, I abandoned it, removed it, did away
> with it.*
>
> *Just as in the last month of the rainy season, in the autumn, when the crops thicken, a cowherd would guard his cows by constantly
> tapping and poking them on this side and that with a stick to check
> and curb them. Why is that? Because he sees that he could be flogged,
> imprisoned, fined or blamed if he let them stray into the crops. So
> too I saw in unwholesome states danger, degradation and defilement...*
>
> [*Two Kinds of Thought*](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn19)

If you use the **wise reflection** method, it is important to focus on the anger rather than on 'yourself'. You must think: "This anger is harmful" (rather than "I am harmful").

The Buddha did not teach the 'self' or 'I' is the ultimate cause of problems & suffering. The Buddha taught 'ignorance' or 'not-knowing' is the ultimate cause of problems.

Therefore, we think/reflect: "Anger is bad & harmful" (and not "I am bad & harmful").

Comment: Thanks for your help Dhammadhatu! I would try to practise what you said the next time I get angry. I should view anger as a separate entity and distance myself away from it.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. And yes, precisely. You should view anger as a separate entity and distance yourself away from it. You are not anger & anger is not you. Anger is a element in nature but is not us & is separate from the clarity of consciousness that can observe anger. My best wishes.